# Using devenv.exe from the command line and specifying the platform

Tags: x86, devenv, anycpu

I'm attempting to compile a visual studio solution using devenv.exe from the command line. I can get it to work but all the projects in the solution are compiled for AnyCPU and I want them to be compiled for x86. Both the debug and release configurations are set to x86 for all projects.

When I compile from within the IDE it works fine. But when I try to build the solution from the command line it always builds all projects for AnyCPU. Is there a way to devenv.exe to build in x86 only?

We are using Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" myproject.sln /Build "Release|x86
```

Comment: That did the trick. The "release|x86" syntax doesn't seem to be in the Microsoft documentation any where. In any case thanks for your help

Comment: You probably don't care any more, but if you don't want to wait until the compilation has finished, use devenv.com instead of .exe.

Comment: devenv.com also sets the ERRORLEVEL, so you can check for success or failure in your build script.

Answer (score 1):

You can for sure use this command: `devenv /?` it will show you everything you want to know and even more.

This is taken from `devenv /?`

> /Build    Builds the solution or project with the specified solution
>   configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms     are
>   possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes   and
>   contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32".

[image]

Comment: The canonical help flag in Windows is `/?`, not `--help`.  (In this case `--help` works because it displays the help message whenever you specify an invalid flag.)

Comment: You're 100% right :D it even says `Unknown switch : -help`. I have updated my answer, Thanks a lot.